# SQL statement retrieves invalid data

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

Have a look at the following SQL statement

```
select * 
from PhoneData 
where  names = 'yohan' 
    and nickName = 'yoises' 
    and mobileNumber1 = 0000000000 or mobileNumber2 = 0000000000
```

In here, there is a problem. That is this return all the results where the phone number is same. There are 2 rows with the same phone number, so it returns both, by ignoring the name, nick name and all. I assume this is because of the "or" statement. How can I solve this? I need to get details who's name=yohan and mobileNumber1 or mobileNumber2 = 000000000.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need some brackets around your OR statements, like this:

```
select * 
from PhoneData 
where names = 'yohan' 
    and nickName = 'yoises' 
    and (mobileNumber1 = 0000000000 
        or mobileNumber2 = 0000000000)
```

Without brackets, it is effectively doing this:

```
select * 
from PhoneData 
where (names = 'yohan' 
    and nickName = 'yoises' 
    and mobileNumber1 = 0000000000) 
        or mobileNumber2 = 0000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing parenthesis:

```
select * from PhoneData where  names = 'yohan' and nickName = 'yoises' and (mobileNumber1 = 0000000000 or mobileNumber2 = 0000000000)
```

The `AND` operator has a different precedence to `OR` so make sure you're explicit when combining them.